# $\mathbb N$ a Banach space?

Tags: banach-spaces

Is $\mathbb N$ a Banach space with the norm $|x-y|$ from $\mathbb R$? I think is Banach space because there is no convergent sequence that is not constant after some $N$. Then all limit points are in the space. But I am not sure.

Comment: Have you looked up the definition of Banach space?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yes. I forgot to regard the structure it have. How stupid of me.

Comment: Not only is it a real question, it even displays some work and has a multiply-upvoted and accepted answer. While there’s no pressing need at this point to reopen the question, the closure is bizarre, to put it politely.

Comment: I agree.  This ain't even a PSQ; it's just short.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It surely is a complete metric space, your proof is correct. Another justification of this would be that it is a closed subspace of the Banach space $(\Bbb R,|\cdot|)$. But it has no linear structure, so it's not a Banach space.

Answer (score 6):

No, a Banach space has to be a vector space over $\mathbb R$.  This is not true for $\mathbb N$ because in general $n\in \mathbb N$ does not mean that $\lambda n\in \mathbb N$ for every $\lambda \in\mathbb R$.